# Adding multiple detailsview datakeys to gridview select parameters

Tags: asp.net, gridview, detailsview

I must be missing the obvious. I have a Details view with 3 values I need to pass to a Gridview.

The idea seems simple.......

These are the Select parameters I am using on the Gridview.

All 3 parameters seems to only pull the first.

Anytime I try to add an index, it throws an exception.

```
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dvAssets" Name="id" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int16" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dvAssets" Name="assetid" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int16" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dvAssets" Name="deviceid" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int16" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Comment: So if I use the PropertyName = "SelectedValue[0]"    I get the following error...   DataBinding: 'System.Int32' does not allow indexed access.

Comment: If I use PropertyName="DataKey[0]" I get the following error.... Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index